# What is the meaning of the syntax: <element #foo />

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am reading a tutorial and I have found a sample code with a line looking like this:

```
<input #foo />
```

I think that it's an input with id="foo". But isn't the correct syntax this one:

```
<input id="foo" />
```

Comment: You're right, unless the tutorial is about some magic parser I don't know about. The writer of the tutorial is just mixing css and html. I hope the rest of the tutorial is somewhat decent.

Comment: Would you be so kind as to let us see the tutorial for ourselves?

Comment: from your markup it seems the tutorial is not only about typescript :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called a template reference variable in Angular. it can refer to a DOM element,Directive or web component etc. According to the official documentation -

```
A template reference variable is often a reference to a DOM element within a template. It can also be a reference to an Angular component or directive or a web component.
```

Source : https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ref-vars

Example : We can use `@ViewChild()` with Template Variable using `ElementRef` to access Native Element. `@ViewChild()` can instantiate `ElementRef` corresponding to a given template reference variable. The template variable name will be passed in `@ViewChild()` as an argument.

HTML :

```
<div>
   Name: <input type="text" #name> <br/>
   City: <input type="text" #city>  
</div>
```

Component code :

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-theme',
    templateUrl: './apptheme.component.html'
})
export class AppThemeComponent implements AfterViewInit {
        @ViewChild('name') 
    private elName : ElementRef;
    @ViewChild('city') 
    private elCity : ElementRef;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
       this.elName.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = 'cyan';
       this.elName.nativeElement.style.color = 'red';      
       this.elCity.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = 'cyan';
       this.elCity.nativeElement.style.color = 'red';          
    }
}
```

using `#name and #city` above we can access the native elements style properties.

Comment: Well, that's just annoying if this TypeScript tutorial is assuming knowledge of Angular.

Comment: @BoltClock well it's a fact according to the HTML OP shared. Angular is unavoidable in this case

Comment: I know. I was taking a dig at the tutorial.

Comment: Can still be something other than Angular, but nice catch. Really confusing syntax, especially without the rest of the attributes shown.